# Alsamixer has extra things that won't go away

Tags: audio, alsa

While trying to put a "pre-amp" slider into Alsamixer, using `/etc/asound.conf`, I managed to get it wrong several times.  Each time I changed something in `/etc/asound.conf` and restarting ALSA, I wound up getting yet another control displayed by Alsamixer.  I've finally hit on the correct contents of `/etc/asound.conf`.  Now how do I get rid of the garbage sliders and buttons?  Doing `apt-get purge alsa*` and reinstalling doesn't help.  Nor does deleting `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` and `~/.asoundrc` do anything.

How is Alsamixer caching these settings and how can I clear it out?

Answer (score 2):

'Virtual' mixer controls are attached to the driver of a 'real' sound card, and are automatically saved to and restored from `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` together with the other controls.

To remove them, you must unload the driver module of your sound card (probably `snd-hda-intel`), and then remove the entries from `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` before reloading the driver.